# When execute "sudo kata-runtime kata-check", it shows " file /usr/share/kata-containers/vmlinuz.container does not exist"

Tags: installation, containers, virtualization, kata-containers

First I install qemu-2.11.1 with commands:

```
./configure --enable-virtfs`
sudo make
sudo make install
```

Then I executed commands in kata-containers/runtime:

```
sudo make
sudo make install
```

After these things, I just checked wheter the environment is suitable for kata-container. But it showed:

```
ERRO[0000] /usr/share/defaults/kata-containers/configuration-qemu.toml: file /usr/share/kata-containers/vmlinuz.container does not exist  arch=amd64 name=kata-runtime pid=66966 source=runtime
```

I found that the /usr/share/kata-containers did not exist at all. I searched for this error message but there was no solutions. I wonder how I deal with this problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks very similar to https://github.com/kata-containers/runtime/issues/2374
Basically, you have only installed a couple of the necessary components for Kata. You also need to install some other components (see the [developers guide](https://github.com/kata-containers/documentation/blob/master/Developer-Guide.md#initial-setup) ).

I agree the `kata-env` command could be a little more useful, and continue to check the rest of the setup though.